# angular2-material button issue in md-toolbar

Tags: angular-material2

I am having issues using md-button inside md-toolbar. Outside of md-toolbar there are no issues. The following code works in md-toolbar

```
<button md-icon-button ></button>
```

But neither of the following is working in md-toolbar

```
<button md-button> </button>
<button md-raised-button> </button>
<a md-button> </a>
```

I get this error:

> Template parse errors:↵More than one component: MdButton,MdButton

I am using "@angular2-material/button": "^2.0.0-alpha.6"

Comment: Can you add more detail with your imports?  it sounds like you might be importing two libraries that declare MdButton...

Comment: The issue was resolved once i upgraded the @angular2-material and its sub-modules to latest release